# Python Group by attribute range

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, python-parser

I have about 6000 points that I need to run a computationally intensive analysis on. My thought process is to break this point layer up into six groups of 1000 points each. I'm trying to do this in ArcGIS ModelBuilder in 10.5 using the field calculator tool. The grouping doesn't really matter, but all of the other attributes to use (city, state, zip) will overwhelmingly put more points into one category and not the other 5 because they are spatially clustered. My plan was to use either the ObjectID, or the unique ID field I created (ObjectID number + letter "A")

My code is as follows:

```
def classify(OBJECTID) :
  if int(OBJECTID) >= 5000 :
    return 6
  elif int(OBJECTID) >= 4000  and int(OBJECTID) <= 4999 :
    return 5
  elif int(OBJECTID) >= 3000  and int(OBJECTID) <= 3999 :
    return 4
  elif int(OBJECTID) >= 2000  and int(OBJECTID) <= 2999 :
    return 3
  elif int(OBJECTID) >=1000 and int(OBJECTID) <= 1999 :
    return 2
  else:
    return 1

classify(!Group_!)
```

However this code is giving all of my points a value of 1. I can't figure out why. I've also tried this with the `int()` portions of code removed and tried using a range statement `int(OBJECTID) in range (4000, 4999):` .

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Can you show your OBJECTIDs? Do they contain trailing or leading spaces? One thing you could do is to print(int(OBJECTID)) to see what values are actually being compared against.

Comment: Sure thing @Jon, I've provided a screenshot of the attribute table from ArcMap.

Comment: Hm, try the print statement to make sure you're passing in what you intend.

Comment: Also looks like ObjectIDs in Arc are stored as unique integers http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/object-id.htm

Comment: Try classify(! objectid!)

Comment: Yeah, my guess is (like Felix suggests) that you're not passing in the objectid.

Comment: Also simple int(!oid!/1000) will do the job.

Comment: @FelixP using classify(! objectid!) gave me an error in my code block. I'm not entirely sure where to use the print(int(OBJECTID) see what what values it's being compared against. Would that be just in a simple field calculator? The OBJECTID/1000 worked when using a short numeric field format, but that made 6 groups with a smaller number allotted to each group because there will be a 0 category now (for all rows with an OBJECTID less than 1000). Not really a big deal since I'm automating it. Thanks!

Comment: No, you'd put the print statement in your script before the if statements (and comment them out for testing). I never use Arc so I don't know where it would print the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're passing your group field into your function instead of ObjectID. Be sure to pass in the ObjectID. Then make use of an [Update Cursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) to update your `Group_` field.

```
fc = r"path\to\feature\class"


#----------

import arcpy

def classify(OBJECTID) :
  if int(OBJECTID) >= 5000 :
    return 6
  elif int(OBJECTID) >= 4000  and int(OBJECTID) <= 4999 :
    return 5
  elif int(OBJECTID) >= 3000  and int(OBJECTID) <= 3999 :
    return 4
  elif int(OBJECTID) >= 2000  and int(OBJECTID) <= 2999 :
    return 3
  elif int(OBJECTID) >=1000 and int(OBJECTID) <= 1999 :
    return 2
  else:
    return 1

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (fc, ["OID@", "Group_"]) as curs:
    for oid, group in curs:
        group = classify (oid)
        curs.updateRow ((oid, group))
```

You can also use [Calculate Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm).

```
fc = r"path\to\feature\class"


#----------

import arcpy

codeblock = """def classify(OBJECTID) :
  if int(OBJECTID) >= 5000 :
    return 6
  elif int(OBJECTID) >= 4000  and int(OBJECTID) <= 4999 :
    return 5
  elif int(OBJECTID) >= 3000  and int(OBJECTID) <= 3999 :
    return 4
  elif int(OBJECTID) >= 2000  and int(OBJECTID) <= 2999 :
    return 3
  elif int(OBJECTID) >=1000 and int(OBJECTID) <= 1999 :
    return 2
  else:
    return 1"""

oidFld = arcpy.Describe (fc).OIDFieldName
arcpy.CalculateField_management (fc, "Group_", "classify (!{}!)".format (oidFld), 
                                 "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock)
```

Results:

[image]